# Parsing xml with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this function where i want to parse the xml with jquery.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {

     var xmlTitle = xml.data;
     alert($(xmlTitle).find('title'));
}
```

I want to alert the title of the the xml like this but it doesn't work. This is what i did, which can be helpful you to see the xml object.

```
alert(xml); 
alert(xml.data);
```

xml alerts: [object Object.]

xml.data alerts: `<data><title>Hello</title><topic>World</topic></data>`

Comment: The title of the xml? What does that mean? The filename?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an element with the tag `title`, which means it's an object, and alerts can't show objects, you should use console.log for that. To show the elements text, you could do:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
     var xmlTitle = xml.find('title');
     alert($(xmlTitle).text());
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwKLs/1/)

If your getting the XML whith a jQuery method that uses `$.ajax`, it should be parsed already, otherwise a good practice is to parse the XML with [**$.parseXML**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to make sure jQuery can treat it the usual way.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
     var xmlTitle = $.parseXML(xml.data);
     alert($(xmlTitle).find('title').text());
}

var xml = {}
    xml.data = '<data><title>Hello</title><topic>World</topic></data>';


xmlParser(xml)​
```

Comment: It's alerting the jQuery object that contains the `<title>` element(s), since that's what's returned by `.find()`. Still, calling `.text()` is the correct answer, assuming there's only one `<title>` element.

Comment: I updated what message.data alerts. My function actually doesn't alert anything when i do alert($(xmlTitle).find('title'));

Comment: @hackio - is the XML properly parsed, added that to my answer, and if you're getting the XML with ajax and a datatype set to XML it should be OK.

Comment: edited, what exactly is `xml.data`, I don't think dot notation would work, unless that is an object containing XML strings, are you sure it's not like in the answer above ?

Comment: actually its done with the channel api(google app engine), so the xml comes from the server and when i do 'xml.data' it alerts the xml string which i am supposed to parse.

Comment: +1, been noticing your nice regex answers lately and thought I'd take a cruise through some oldies—of course this one is "anti-regex"  :)

Comment: @zx81 - thanks, regex isn't really my thing so I usually try to avoid it if I can, but sometimes a regex really is the right way to go, and at least knowing the basics is crucial for almost any developer in any language, and I'm still trying to understand a little more complicated lookbehind/aheads etc.

Comment: `at least knowing the basics is crucial` Yes, isn't it so...? About lookarounds I wouldn't presume to give you advice as your regex looks great, and I'm sure you've heard of Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd Ed (Friedl). :) For my part I'm blown away by (and finding it impossible to understand) some regexps by whizzes, such as [Kobi's regex to solve a maze](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/solving-mazes-using-regular-expressions/)!